# vue-google-maps - How do I set Map Styles?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js, vue-component

So I'm using [vue-google-maps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-google-maps) with [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/), and have placed a map on the body. I want to add some styling to the map, but don't know how to go about it. When using Vanilla.js, I could just add styles with `theMap.setOptions({styles: style_array})`, but how do I do that with [vue-google-maps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-google-maps)?

This is my setup:

**DOM**

```
<google-map style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; left:0; top:0"
            :center="{ lat: 30.2672, lng: -97.7431 }"
            :zoom="12"
>
</google-map>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.6.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.21/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-google-maps/0.1.17/vue-google-maps.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/[JS-FILE]"></script>
```

**JS**

```
VueGoogleMap.load({
    'key': '***'
});

Vue.component('google-map', VueGoogleMap.Map);
new Vue({
    el: 'body',
    data: {
        mapStyle: mapStyle
    }
});
```

I´ve tried adding style to the api-key & sat `:styles: "style_array"` to the DOM, but nothing has worked. Does anyone know how to set map styles with Vue.js?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After reading the vue-google-maps documentation thoroughly, I realised there was an option to set `":options: [style]"` when initiating the google-map element.

I set the style in **JS** and passed it to the client like this:

**DOM**

```
<google-map style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; left:0; top:0"
            :center="{ lat: 30.2672, lng: -97.7431 }"
            :zoom="12"
            v-bind:options="mapStyle"
>
</google-map>
```

**JS**

```
var mapStyle = [style];

VueGoogleMap.load({
    'key': '***'
});

Vue.component('google-map', VueGoogleMap.Map);
new Vue({
    el: 'body',
    data: {
        mapStyle: {styles: mapStyle}
    }
});
```